# How do I get an estimate for this nonlocal ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following nonlocal ODE on $[1,\infty)$:

$$r^2 f''(r) + 2rf'(r)-l(l+1) f(r) = -\frac{(f'(1) + f(1))}{r^2}$$
$$f(1) = \alpha$$
$$\lim_{r\to \infty} f(r) = 0$$
where $l$ is a positive integer and $\alpha$ is a real number.

Define the following norm $\lVert \cdot \lVert$:
$$\lVert f \lVert^2 := \int_1^{\infty} r^2 f'(r)^2 dr + l(l+1) \int_1^{\infty} f(r)^2 dr$$

I want to prove the estimate:
$$\lVert f \lVert \leq C \sqrt{l(l+1)}|\alpha|$$
for some constant $C$ independent of $\alpha$, $l$ and $f$. But I am stuck.

Here is what I tried. Multiply both sides by $f$ and integrate by parts to get:

$$\begin{align} 
\lVert f \lVert^2 = \int_1^{\infty} r^2 f^2 + \int_1^{\infty} l(l+1) f^2 &= f'(1)f(1)+(f'(1)+f(1)) \int_1^{\infty} \frac{f}{r^2} \\
&\leq f'(1)\alpha + \frac{(f'(1)+ \alpha)}{3}\sqrt{\int_1^{\infty} f^2}\\
&\leq f'(1)\alpha + \frac{(f'(1)+ \alpha)}{3}\lVert f \lVert
\end{align}$$
where I used Cauchy-Schwartz in the before last line. I am not sure how to continue and how to get rid of the $f'(1)$ term.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to multiply both sides by $f'(r)$ too.

Comment: I tried but I still see $f'(1)$ which I don't know how to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we deal with the $f'(1)$ term:

\begin{align}
f'(1) &= -\int_1^{\infty} f''(r)dr \\
&= -\int_1^{\infty} \left[ -\frac{f(1)+f'(1)}{r^4} + \frac{l(l+1)}{r^2} f(r) - \frac{1}{r} f'(r) \right]dr
\end{align}

Since $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^4}dr < 1$, we can just solve for $f'(1)$ and use Cauchy Schwartz to estimate it by $|f(1)|$ and $\lVert f \lVert$. Then I can easily get the estimate I wanted.